# Explain this code please :)

Tags: javascript

(This code is written in JavaScript. Can you please explain what this program does and explain what happens if the value of y is changed to 3 and then to 4.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var temp = 14;
            var y = 2;
            temp <<= y;
            document.write(temp);
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep they are. Can you help?

Comment: How do you know I'm in Duffryn High School?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should instead try learning.

Answer (score 3):

> temp <<= y;

<< is a left shift operator, if appends 2 bits to right.

if 14 was represented in binary as `1101`, after this statement it becomes `110100` which is `56` `== 14 * 4`

> explain what happens if the value of y is changed to 3 and then to 4.

simply then `temp` is shifted to the left by as many binary digits, it becomes

```
14 << 3 == 14 * 8 == 112

14 << 4 == 14 * 16 == 224
```